# Machine Learning classifier AdaBoost for C#

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, adaboost

Is there a popular and stable library in C# for the AdaBoost algorithm?
Does such a library contain different flavors of boosting besides the classic AdaBoost (such as GentleBoost, LogitBoost, etc. )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/boosting.html) supports the basic flavors of AdaBoost (Discrete, Real, Logit and Gentle). This library is in C/C++ but you can use the C# wrapper called [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/) although the API is more limited (mainly Train() and Predict() methods) than the C/C++ one.

You can also use [Accord.Net](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/N_Accord_MachineLearning_Boosting.htm) but I haven't tried it yet.